# Birt report file path

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, birt

I'm trying to setup Birt running under Jetty. I can get the "congratulations" report to run:

http://10.10.11.1:8080/reports/frameset?__report=test.rptdesign&sample=my+parameter

However, I am not able to get any other reports to run. I have the BIRT viewer running from the "reports" context. Trying to run one of the sample reports (placed in the same directory as the birt.war file).

Here is what I've tried:
http://10.10.11.1:8080/reports/frameset?__report=SalesInvoice.rptdesign
SalesInvoice.rptdesign is placed in the same directory as the birt.war file

http://10.10.11.1:8080/reports/frameset?__report=/templates/SalesInvoice.rptdesign
Where templates is a sub-directory of the context for birt. This results in:

- There is no report design object available.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I have just encountered the same problem and I solved it by changing

```
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.22" id="1">
```

to

```
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.17" id="1">
```

I think it is because your Birt Viewer can not render report file for previous versions, but if you don't use the features of newer version, then you can render your report by changing the report version manually.

Other solution is downloading newer version of Birt Viewer that is compatible with your current Birt Report Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Birt, but could it be that your custom template file needs to be made executable?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a bit embarrasing, but I had the same error and it didn't come from any version conflict. I simply had a spelling error:

r**tp**document instead of r**pt**document. :(